# Getting an error that states "printf.c: No such file or directory" while using GDB on a very basic C program for temperature conversion

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, lib

- **This is what GDB is showing me**

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x722: file homework1.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/aj_the_kid/ECE_373/homework1 
Breakpoint 1, main () at homework1.c:4
4   {
(gdb) step
8     printf("Enter the temperature (for conversion) in Fahrenheit:  ");
(gdb) step
__printf (
    format=0x555555554838 "Enter the temperature (for conversion) in Fahrenheit:  ") at printf.c:28
28  printf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
 #0  __printf (
    format=0x555555554838 "Enter the temperature (for conversion) in Fahrenheit:  ") at printf.c:28
 #1  0x0000555555554742 in main () at homework1.c:8
(gdb) next
32  in printf.c
(gdb) next
33  in printf.c
(gdb) step
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7dd0760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, 
    format=0x555555554838 "Enter the temperature (for conversion) in Fahrenheit:  ", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffde20) at vfprintf.c:1244
1244    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) step
1275    in vfprintf.c
```

- **And this is my test program for Linux**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float temp_F, temp_C;

  // Prompt user for input (i.e. temp in Fahrenheit)
  printf("Enter the temperature (for conversion) in Fahrenheit:  ");
  scanf("%f\n", &temp_F);

  // Convert F to C
  temp_C = (temp_F - 32) * (5/9);
  printf("The temperature in Celsius is: %.2f\n", temp_C);

  return 0;

}
```

- **EDIT: fixed code to support float type arithmetic**

But I am still getting the issue where it requires me to input the degrees in Fahrenheit again in an empty line like it didnt capture the user input the first time

**Terminal View**

```
aj_the_kid@AJs-Sandbox:~/ECE_373$ rm file1
aj_the_kid@AJs-Sandbox:~/ECE_373$ gcc -g -o file1 file1.c
aj_the_kid@AJs-Sandbox:~/ECE_373$ ./file1
Enter the temperature (for conversion) in Fahrenheit:  32

32
The temperature in celcius is: 0.00
aj_the_kid@AJs-Sandbox:~/ECE_373$
```

Comment: any and all help is appreciated since the only similar issues i found are for assembly ...

Comment: `5/9` is 0. You're doing integer division, which truncates towards 0. You could change it to `5.0/9.0`

Comment: `vfprintf.c: No such file or directory`: you're trying to step into a library function for which you don't have source code.  However your actual code bug is pointed out above by @user3386109...

Comment: please update your question with the modified source code

Comment: @AJtheKidd Oh, that's because of the `\n` in the `scanf`. `scanf` is a little strange about whitespace. Putting the `\n` at the end of the format string tells `scanf` to skip all whitespace until the user types non-whitespace character and presses enter. You can fix it by removing the `\n`.

Comment: @user3386109  THANK YOUUUUU!!!!!! i didn't know that about scanf so i figured there was something else going on under the hood that was messing it up! i appreciate the help man !

Comment: @rtx13  i updated it! (& sorry I'm also pretty new to stackoverflow so I'm not up to date on the appropriate syntax or actions here) but thank you for your help!

Comment: @AJtheKidd Any time. Glad to help!

Comment: @AJtheKidd You are welcome.  Ideally user3386109 would post an actual Answer and then you could vote it up and accept it, but in this instance it's sufficient to up vote their comment.

Comment: @user3386109, true, but that was just the first obstacle with other bugs looming that you took care of

Comment: @rtx13  oh okay thanks!  would it be appropriate to now update the source code with the correction made in the ```scanf```` line? or should i leave the bug in the source code so users can make sense of the comments and see where the error is?

Comment: in general, always use the 'next' command to step (automatically) until the next (visible to you) statement in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

The error message from gdb `vfprintf.c: No such file or directory` is due to the fact that you're trying to step into a library function for which you don't have source code.

The problem in the calculation is that the division `(5/9)` is performed as integer division. So the result is 0. This can be fixed by changing to `(5.0/9.0)`

And the `scanf` problem is due to the `\n` at the end of the format string. `scanf` is a little strange about whitespace. Putting the `\n` at the end of the format string tells scanf to skip all whitespace until the user types non-whitespace character and presses enter. You can fix it by removing the `\n`